# how to perform FFILL() in PANDAS based on 'ent_id' and 'val' columns if it don't exist for successive date then ffill needed to be done else not?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

let's say i have a data frame as

```
effective_date,ent_id,val
2020-02-03,101,aa
2020-02-03,102,bn
2020-02-03,103,bd
2020-02-03,105,bv
2020-02-03,106,bs
2020-02-03,107,ba
2020-02-03,109,be


2020-02-04,101,aa
2020-02-04,102,ab
2020-02-04,103,
2020-02-04,104,kl
2020-02-04,105,ad

2020-02-06,101,aa
2020-02-06,102,
2020-02-06,103,bd
2020-02-06,105,bv
2020-02-06,106,cs
2020-02-06,107,
2020-02-06,109,ce
2020-02-06,113,cd
2020-02-06,115,cv
2020-02-06,117,ca
```

now i wanted to perform forward fill logic on the bases of `ent_id`and `val` column if it doesn't exist in successive date it will perform forward fill for entire column and in successive data e.g. `2020-02-03,107,ba` on successive data it get fill forwarded as `2020-02-04,107,ba` but if the `ent_id` and `val` exist in successive date it will remain intact in successive date no other column value is affected by previous date data e.g. `2020-02-03,103,bd` on successive date it remains intact as `2020-02-04,103,`.

so the output would be like

```
effective_date,ent_id,val
2020-02-03,101,aa
2020-02-03,102,bn
2020-02-03,103,bd
2020-02-03,105,bv
2020-02-03,106,bs
2020-02-03,107,ba
2020-02-03,109,be


2020-02-04,101,aa
2020-02-04,102,ab
2020-02-04,103,
2020-02-04,104,kl
2020-02-04,105,ad
2020-02-04,106,bs
2020-02-04,107,ba
2020-02-04,109,be

2020-02-05,101,aa
2020-02-05,102,ab
2020-02-05,103,
2020-02-05,104,kl
2020-02-05,105,ad
2020-02-05,106,bs
2020-02-05,107,ba
2020-02-05,109,be

2020-02-06,101,aa
2020-02-06,102,
2020-02-06,103,bd
2020-02-06,104,kl
2020-02-06,105,bv
2020-02-06,106,cs
2020-02-06,107,
2020-02-06,109,ce
2020-02-06,113,cd
2020-02-06,115,cv
2020-02-06,117,ca
```

my effort

```
(df.replace(np.nan,987654321).pivot(index='effective_date', columns='ent_id')
   .ffill().asfreq('D',method='ffill')replace(987654321,np.nan).stack().reset_index()
)
```

this is catering all the requirement but is there any better way of doing it pls suggest.